# Android Dagger - How to Inject from other module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, module, dagger-2

I've multiple modules in my app, each one of them have his own Module for UI Injection.

Now, i want to have "feed" fragment that have a some pieces from other modules.
So i trying doing it using FragmentContainerView.
I want to Inject the fragment that defined on other module. I'm trying to "include" my other fragment, so i can navigate into this fragment, but if i'm try to inject it, i'm getting this following error:

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] DotsFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.

Any idea how can i do it?

HomeModule:

```
@Module(
includes = [
    DotsModule::class
    ]
)
abstract class HomeModule {


}
```

DotsModule:

```
@Module
abstract class DotsModule {

    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeDotsFragment(): DotsFragment
  
}
```

HomeFragment:

```
@Inject
lateinit var dotsFragment: DotsFragment
```

Answer (score 1):

Just push the Fragment into the container [as described in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic), and don't worry about the injection. You don't even need the explicit inclusion of DotsModule from HomeModule, though you may choose to keep it, especially if HomeModule is in a different Activity. DotsFragment will [inject itself in `onAttach`](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/android#injecting-fragment-objects).

Unlike most classes that use Dagger injection, Fragments can't be injected in their constructors: Android will only call the [zero-arg or one-arg `Fragment()` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#Fragment()), so there isn't room for other constructor parameters. When you see your `abstract fun contributeDotsFragment()` function with [`@ContributesAndroidInjector`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html), it is not the case that DotsFragment is available on your graph to be constructed or provided. Instead, Dagger does some magic<sup>1</sup> that allows the Fragment to have its `@Inject`-labeled fields populated<sup>2</sup> once you [call `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` in `onAttach`](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/android#injecting-fragment-objects), which might happen in [DaggerFragment](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/android/support/DaggerFragment.html) if you inherit from that. Your Fragment has to assume that anything marked `@Inject` is `null` until the Fragment is attached.

Consequently, if you need an instance of DotsFragment, you can just call `DotsFragment()` or delegate to your FragmentManager's FragmentFactory (which will likely just call `DotsFragment()`). You can also use [overloads to `FragmentTransaction.replace(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment%3E,android.os.Bundle)) that take a `Class<Fragment>` rather than a Fragment instance.

The Fragment will inject itself later in `onAttach`, as it would if Android itself called the constructor. If you interact with the Fragment before that, be careful, as its `@Inject`-annotated fields will not be populated yet. If you need to interact with the Fragment in ways that use Dagger-provided instances, it may be best to create a Bundle that the Fragment can use to initialize itself in `onCreate`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Behind the scenes, [dagger.android](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/android) creates a code-generated [subcomponent](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/subcomponents) instance, probably called `DotsModule_BindDotsFragment.DotsFragmentSubcomponent`, and registers that subcomponent as an [`AndroidInjector.Factory<DotsFragment>`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/android/AndroidInjector.Factory.html) in a Map. The generated subcomponent receives all the `modules` you set on the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation as well as all the scope annotations you set on the `abstract fun`. In `onAttach` (yours or DaggerFragment's), the call to `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` reads from that Map, finds the Injector/Subcomponent, creates an instance, and uses that to inject the Fragment with its own set of `@FragmentScope` instances.

<sup>2</sup> The `@Inject`-annotated methods will be called too. That's *method injection*, compared to *field injection*; the general term is *members injection* for all of the post-constructor initialization Dagger can do.